# Php undefinded variable

Tags: php, validación

Hola este formulario me funcionaba, no se que pasa ahora.

```
<form action="cliente_ingresado.php" method="post" >
<div>
    <label for="identificacion" >Identificación:  </label> &nbsp;
    <input type="text" name="identificacion" id="identificacion" required="required"/>
</div>

<div>
    <label for="nombre" >Nombre: </label>&nbsp;
    <input type="text" name="nombre" id="nombre" required="required"/>
</div>

<div>
    <label for="direccion">Dirección: </label>&nbsp;
    <input type="text" name="direccion" id="direccion" />
</div>

<div>
    <label for="telefono">Teléfono: </label>&nbsp;
    <input type="text" id="telefono" name="telefono"/>
</div>

<div>
    <label for="correo">Correo: </label>&nbsp;
    <input type="email" id="correo" name="correo"/>
</div>

<!--<div>
    <label for="sexo">Sexo: </label>&nbsp;
    <input type="text" id="sexo" name="sexo"/>
</div> -->

<div>
    <label id="label1" name='sexo2'>Turno </label> &nbsp;    
    <input type='radio' name='Masculino' value='M'  checked> Masculino &nbsp;
    <input type='radio' name='Femenino' value='F' > Femenino<br><br>
</div>

<div>
    <label for="estado_civil">Estado Civil:  </label>&nbsp;
    <input type="text" id="estado_civil" name="estado_civil"/>
</div>

<div class="button">
    <button type="submit" name="submit" onclick="validarFormulario()">Guardar</button> &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;

    <button type="button">Limpiar</button>
</div>
```

Cuando paso los valores a la otra página, me sale que las variables no están definidas

```
if(isset($_POST['identificacion']) &&
        isset($_POST['nombre']) && 
        isset($_POST['direccion']) && 
        isset($_POST['telefono']) && 
        isset($_POST['correo']) &&
        //isset($_POST['sexo']) &&
        isset($_POST['estado_civil']))
    {
```

Comment: Probé tu código y no me lanza ningún error ¿cuál es la descripción completa del error?

Comment: Hola John, tal y como está definido el código en la pregunta, no parece haber ningún error (al menos con el código compartido). ¿En qué línea te sale el error de que no hay una variable definida? ¿Puedes poner el mensaje completo para ver cuál es la variable que no está definida? Lee [ask] y cómo crear un [mcve] para más información.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lo que ocurre es que para utilizar `isset` con múltiples variables, no se usa el operador `&&` si no que las mismas variables solo se separan por comas; entonces tu código debería quedar:

```
if(isset($_POST['identificacion'], $_POST['nombre'], $_POST['direccion'], $_POST['telefono'], $_POST['correo'], $_POST['sexo'], $_POST['estado_civil']))
    {
         echo "exito";  
    }
```

Del mismo modo no necesitas redeclarar la función isset, basta con que la escribas una vez

**EJEMPLO:**

```
$num1 = "hi";
$num2 = "bye";

if(isset($num1, $num2)){
  echo "exito";
}else{
  echo "fallo";
}
```

Comment: Hice el cambio, sigue saliendo el mismo error

Comment: Hice el cambio, se solucionó gracias Alfredo. Soy nuevo en php, me baso en tutoriales que encuentro...

Comment: Éste no puede ser el motivo por el que fallaba. Se pueden tener varios `isset` unidos con `&&` y sería válido, porque devolverían el mismo valor que un único `isset` con varios parámetros (otra cosa es que fuese menos eficiente). @JhonHernández ¿hiciste algún cambio más en el código aparte de éste?

Answer (score 0):

No puedes poner comentarios dentro de los IF's a no ser que sean en el Final

```html
if ( isset($_POST['identificacion']) && isset($_POST['nombre']) && isset($_POST['direccion']) && isset($_POST['telefono']) && isset($_POST['correo']) && isset($_POST['estado_civil']) // Coment ) { 
       // Code Function
    }
```

Comment: en si ese no es el error

Comment: ¿Desde cuando en un condicional que utiliza operadores aritmeticos utilizas comas? Tu le estas generando un fallo... Ademas las comas solo se utilizan para diferenciar propiedades en los arrays...

Comment: Oye no te enfades..

Comment: No estoy enfadado solo que hay cosas que no tienen sentido, y programando pasa siempre hasta que ves tus propios fallos.

Comment: El código no es mío, lo encontré en internet y le puse los nombres de mis variables, si hay cosas que no tienen sentido, no es mi culpa

Comment: Esto respuesta es incorrecta, en un `if` si pueden haber comentarios (tanto de línea como de bloque), y ten en cuenta que en la respuesta de Alfredo Paz, las comas no van en el condicional sino en la función [`isset`](http://php.net/manual/es/function.isset.php) donde sí están permitidas para separar parámetros). Edit: aunque veo que Alfredo editó su respuesta para corregir un error que tenía los paréntesis mal puestos.

Comment: Como no los pongas al final del condicional no te funcionaran...

Comment: @PolFlórezViciana los comentarios de bloque podrían ponerse (casi) en cualquier parte del condicional sin afectar su funcionamiento. Los comentarios de línea se podrían usar para comentar una línea (siempre que no rompa la sintaxis del `if`, como era el caso)